# How the IN operator can be applied on Spring SpEL evaluation?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-el

Currently I have a rule engine system using Spring Expression Language (SpEL) (Java) that allows us to create multiple rules dynamically using some operators, e.g: `IS`, `IS NOT`, `IN LIST`, `NOT IN LIST`.

Assuming that I have the following:

1. `Entity.value = List<String>` with 6000 (number of words) of size. (stored in the DB)
2. `String` with a big size (description texts), with an average of 10000 words. (received on the HTTP request)

When I build the expression on my `EvaluationContext`, I'm using the following for `IS` and `IS_NOT` operator:

```
    static final String IS_OPERATOR = ".matches(\".*\\b%s\\b.*\")";
    static final String IS_NOT_OPERATOR = ".matches(\"^((?!\\b%s\\b).)*\")";
```

For operator `IN` I'm using the following, where I have multiple `REGEXP_VALUE_QUOTE` splitted by `REGEXP_VALUES_SEPARATOR` inside of `IN_OPERATOR`.

```
    public static final String IN_OPERATOR = ".matches(\"%s\")";
    public static final String REGEXP_VALUE_QUOTE = ".*\\b%s\\b.*";
    public static final String REGEXP_VALUES_SEPARATOR = "|";
```

In this `IN` operator I'm facing **huge performance issues** (taking more than 2 seconds and some times more than 30 seconds, depends on the size) on the evaluation. When I try to check if one of my exact words exists on the huge `String`.

Taking in consideration that I can have multiple rules created using this `IN` operator, this evaluation can be executed multiple times in the same process.

Do you have any suggestion to apply this `IN` operator without affecting the performance?

Comment: Go for server side pagination

Comment: Instead of using regex, try registering a function in which you will write a java code to check IN operation, I believe it will take less time